# Python (Inspect) Get functions inside a function

Tags: python, inspect

I need a function that give me all functions from inside a function.
Here is my example target, the method that I need is the magic_function_finder (untested, fast writed, maybe not working at last.)

```
error = {"code": -1, "name":"TEST", "desc": "TEST ERROR"}
class Something:
    @staticmethod
    def buildError(errorObj):        
        return errorObj

class AnotherThing:
    def f1():
        raise Something.buildError(error);

def f2(arg):
    t = AnotherThing()
    t.f1()

def get_inside_funcs(func, ret=[]):
    for func, args in magic_function_finder(f2):        
        if(Something.buildError is func):
            ret.append(args)
            return ret
        else:
            return get_inside_funcs(func, ret)

print get_inside_funcs(f2)
>>[{"code": -1, "name":"TEST", "desc": "TEST ERROR"}]
```

Comment: Do you mean function calls or function definitions?

Comment: Python is a dynamic language, so the only way to get the inner functions is to run the parent function (`f2` in your example) and inspect the local variables using e.g. [`sys.settrace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.settrace).

Comment: the problem is that I can't run just a function, there a much different database calls and another things